# Using actionbar before API Level 11

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm currently trying to create an `ActionBar` for my Android application. But I need it to work in Android 2.2 and 2.3 too. Is there any way to implement `ActionBar` in Android 2.3/2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). Just add the library to your Android project and overwrite `Activity` with `SherlockActivity`, so you have all the possibilities of an Actionbar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the actionbar with [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). It is simple to install and can do everything you need. For the beginning you can [start here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) to read.

Answer (score 1):

[ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) is a library that makes almost all features of the ActionBar available on Android 2.1 and up. When you use a API Level that supports the action bar natively it will automatically use the native action bar instead.